# What is the value of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty i^n$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty i^n=\frac{1}{1-i}$?

$|i|=1$. Is this series convergent?

Comment: Is the series $1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots$ convergent? According to a similar idea to yours it should converge to $1/2$. Does this make sense (sum of a bunch of integers becoming a non-integer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series clearly is not convergent, because the terms do not tend to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

No the series does not converge according to the divergence test.

The answer that you have provided  is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not convergent.  Note that the terms cycle through $1,i,-1,-i,1,i,-1,-i\ldots$ so the sum oscillates through four values as well.  You are on the circle of convergence of the geometric series where convergence is not guaranteed.